# Input text dentro de If

Tags: php, select, input, if

Olá, estou fazendo um formulário e gostaria que algumas perguntas (em formato input)
aparecessem apenas se fosse selecionado certa resposta no select anterior.

```
Você trabalha no Desktop ou no Notebook?:
<select name="pc1">
<option selected="selected"> </option>
<option>Desktop</option>
<option>Notebook</option>
</select><br>
No caso de usar Desktop, quantos monitores?:
<input type="text" name="numtela" size="5" /><br>
```

Invés da pergunta "No caso de usar Desktop", gostaria que a pergunta somente aparecesse caso seja selecionado "Desktop", imagino que seja algo como:

```
<?php
if ($pc1 = $Desktop) {
No caso de usar Desktop, quantos monitores?:
<input type="text" name="numtela" size="5" /><br>
}
?>
```

Porém não consegui fazer funcionar (comecei hoje a programar em php, não sei nada nada nada)

Comment: Está faltando alguns detalhes, mas de antemão ,  o sinal para fazer a comparação é `==`...

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso, para mostrar ou esconder um contéudo(o chamado toggle), você pode usar Javascript ao invés de php.

primeiro atribua um valor para cada `option` e dê um id para o `select`, a pergunta e o `input`.

Teste o código abaixo.

```js
//esconde a pergunta e o input
document.getElementById("perguntamonitores").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('monitores').style.display = 'none';

function mostrarpergunta() {
    //Se for selecionado o desktop, mostra o <p> e o <input> como bloco(mas pode ser como flex também)
    let select = document.getElementById("desk/note")
    let opcao = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    if (opcao === "desk"){
        document.getElementById("perguntamonitores").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('monitores').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Você trabalha no Desktop ou no Notebook?</p>
<select name="pc1" id="desk/note" onblur="mostrarpergunta();">
    <option selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="desk">Desktop</option>
    <option value="note">Notebook</option>
</select>
<br>
<p id="perguntamonitores">No caso de usar Desktop, quantos monitores?</p>
<input id="monitores" type="text" name="numtela" size="5" />
<br>
```

caso você queira que ao aparecer tenha uma transição ou um estilo css especifico para mostrar e esconder, sugiro que ao invés de usar o `document.getElementById('id').style.display = 'block';` use o [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Espero ter ajudado João